# How can I disable auto login after registration in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, fortify

In using laravel 8 with fortify so I don have

> App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

First you must create a controller preferably in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` called `RegisteredUserController`, in this controller you must overwrite the method **store** of the class **RegisteredUserController**.

Copy the `store` method to your new controller and delete the line `$this->guard->login($user);`.

It should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse;

class RegisteredUserController
    extends \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController
{

    public function store(Request $request, CreatesNewUsers $creator): RegisterResponse {
        event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));
        return app(RegisterResponse::class);
    }

}
```

Finally change the default `/register` path that points to your new controller.

```
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisteredUserController@store');
```

Comment: I came to thank you for taking the time to answer this question. It is the most practical solution I have found so far. It solved the issue of automatic Fortify login after registering a user.

I'm just going to mention an alternative when adding the route with the custom controller:

`// Above, in the header of the web.php file of the router`
`use App \ Http \ Controllers \ Auth \ RegisteredUserController;`
``
`// Below, when declaring the route with the custom controller`
`Route :: post ('/ register', [RegisteredUserController :: class, 'store']);`

Answer (score 3):

Fortify will automatically login an user only if you return the user from the `CreateNewUser` class. Instead of returning the created user, throw an exception along with a flash message. Fortify will try to redirect you to the home page and will return you back to the login page as user is not authenticated showing you the flash message. Below is a peek at the process in the file `App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser`.

```php
public function create(array $input)
{
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'email',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique(User::class),
        ],
        'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
    ])->validate();

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password'])
    ]);

    event(new Registered($user));

    flash('Registration successful! Awaiting approval from admin.')
        ->success()
        ->important();

    throw new \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException\AuthenticationException();
}
```

I think there might be other solution to hook into any of the Fortify events to do that even more gracefully.