# Laravel jetstream sesssion issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have an issue with the laravel jetstream but I am not that experienced with it yet. So, I am working on the hospital app and the issue is with the sessions. As you know when we create a new user with jetstream it automatically creates a profile too ***BUT*** it also automatically wants to log in that user into the dashboard which means that it will break other sessions. I see there a potential security issue and I would like to get rid of it if there is someone who can tell me how.

I know that because I am testing on the same browser it is causing this issue but we never can be 100% sure that it won't make some kind of bugs in the future.

I have created a controller and logic which allows "guests" to make an appointment request for examination but then my "admin" breaks because when a guest creates a request I am creating a new user model, patient model and appointment model with many-to-many...

So when the user sends us a request it looks like this:

```
public function store(RequestedAppointmentRequest $request)
{
    $usernameExplode = explode(' ', $request->name); //Take users name and remove space
    $usernamePassword = strtolower($usernameExplode[0].$usernameExplode[1]); //Take users name, remove space and join firstname and lastname to string
    $usernameUsername = strtolower($usernameExplode[0] . '_' . $usernameExplode[1]); //Take users name, swap space for dash and put lowercase letters

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'username' => $usernameUsername,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($usernamePassword),
        'role_id' => 3
    ]);

    $patient = Patient::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'alergies' => $request->alergies,
        'birth' => $request->birth,
        'blood_type' => $request->blood_type,
    ]);

    $appointment = Appointment::create([
        'appointment_title' => $request->appointment_title,
        'diagnosis' => $request->diagnosis,
        'appointment_special_note' => $request->note,
        'appointment_statuses_id' => 1,
        'appointment_date' => $request->appointment_date,
    ]);

    $appointment->users()->attach($patient->user_id);

    session()->flush('success', 'Appointment request has been sent!');
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

After this, it will automatically try to log in to that user (it will create a session) but I don't want that. Is there any way that I can reconfigure that part?

Comment: The `store` method you're showing will not log you to the new user. Your explanation about session and _I know that because I am testing on the same browser_ confuses me. The session is linked to your browser, not to the tab. If you login on a tab, you will be login on the second tab as well when you hit refresh. You can't have both session at the same time, unless you have one in private navigation or you're using an another browser.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier hi there :D Thanks for the explanation and that is exactly what I thought with that sentence :D Is there any way to change the behaviour of the jetstream not to log automatically after "registration". Because, now when someone sends a request it consider it like the newly registered user, right? These credentials will be sent to the user by email so they can log in later on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable auto login after registration in laravel 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397645/how-can-i-disable-auto-login-after-registration-in-laravel-8) _(Note: Jetstream uses Fortify under the hood)_

Comment: It seems like it might work but is there any way that looks cleaner than this one or?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It's either rewrite or extend the controller. You can customize the Action, but the login is hardcoded in the controller. https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/src/Http/Controllers/RegisteredUserController.php#L56 By the way, from my observations, most of the users won't change their password after logged until they are logged out, forget the email or lost the post-it. Their password can easily be guessed. I strongly recommend to generate more secure and randomized passwords.