# Don't log in automatically after register user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need to make the new user registration to be available only to logged in users. The thing is that when I fill the form for registration, it automatically logs in with the new account, even if I'm already logged in with another account. I'm using Laravel auth for the login system.
My registerController is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

RegisterUsers is this:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait RegistersUsers
{
use RedirectsUsers;

/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during registration.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}

/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
}
}
```

I've tried to remove "$this->guard()->login($user);" this part of the RegistersUsers, but it didn't change anything..

Edit: Someone sent me a link to this discussion-> [How can I disable auto login after registration in laravel 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397645/how-can-i-disable-auto-login-after-registration-in-laravel-8)
but I'm not using Fortify (not that I know of), and the solution in that discussion is to delete this line -> "$this->guard()->login($user);", which I already did (as seen in the question).

Comment: for the person who posted the other question here in stack.. i've done that solution, wich is to delete the "$this->guard->login($user);", i even wrote that in the question, but it didn't work

Comment: Where are you deleting the `$this->guard()->login($user);`? Can you tell me the full path of the file?

Comment: Have you tried adding a code or something to the last function registered... there could be no other problem with the rest of the code

Comment: @aceraven777 App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController

Comment: that's not the path of the file. That the namespace. is the file inside the `vendor` directory?

Comment: Brian, i haven't tried to add a code.. The auto login function is something that Laravel does on its own, so there must be a way to override this, or just comment the part where it does this..

Comment: That is the path to the file. It is inside the "Auth" folder, just like the path i've shown

Answer (score 2):

You can just create new users, not registering new ones but creating. All you need to do is hashing users' passwords in your function and call it by post method

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User; // don't forget to include this lines at the top  

public function createUser(Request $request){
     $data = $request->all();
     $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);
     User::create($data);
     return redirect()->to('/redirect-to-route-after-creating-new-user');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'logout the user' ?
I want to create a new user, only if i'm already logged in in another account. So no one needs to logout, it's just that it shouldn't log in.

Comment: @EduardoK updated my answer, try creating new users not registering